# MasterDetailPage: Different behaviour on UWP / Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using MasterDetailPage in Xamarin.Forms it behaves as aspected in Android. Just like a normal Navigation Drawer. Please notice the correct behaviour of the slide-in mechanism and the correct placement of the hamburger-button. The Buttons in the menu work great as well.

[image]  [image]

The UWP App looks like this. Notice, there is no hamburger-button:
[image]

After klicking on a menu-button, the menu is gone without a possibility to get it back:
[image]

Here are some code excerpts:

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
    }
...
```

MenuPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WordDeck.MenuPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WordDeck;assembly=WordDeck"
             Title="WordDeck."
             MasterBehavior="Default">

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Text="Neues Spiel"
                Clicked="MainPage_Clicked"></Button>
        <Button Text="Deck Verwaltung"
                Clicked="DeckManager_Clicked"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <local:MainPage></local:MainPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

MenuPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Detail = new MainPage();
            Title = "WordDeck.";
            IsPresented = false;
        }

        private void DeckManager_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Detail = new DeckManagerPage();
            Title = "Deck Verwaltung";
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

MainPage and DeckManagerPage are nearly empty and of type ContentPage.

**Why is there no menu Button on UWP?**

Comment: Maybe you need to update your Xamarin.Forms nuget packages?  I just took most of your code above and I have a hamburger menu, and I can collapse and open the menu.  I am running Windows 10 UWP as the test.  It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're running the UWP app as a desktop app and not on the phone. If you run the app on a mobile phone or emulator you should see the menu as on Android.

If you want to use the hamburger behaviour when running as a desktop app set `MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover` on your MasterDetailPage

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the IsPresented on the desktop hides the drawer.
One way to handle this is not to hide on desktop or tablet.

For example...

```
// Called from each Clicked Event
private void SetPresentedVisability()
{
    switch (Device.Idiom)
    {
        case TargetIdiom.Phone:
            IsPresented = false;
            break;
        case TargetIdiom.Desktop:
        case TargetIdiom.Tablet:
        case TargetIdiom.Unsupported:
            IsPresented = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternately you could ignore any non phone IsPresented setting.

```
IsPresented = (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone) ? false : true;
```